# json_decode multidimensional from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have this json saved in my database in a column called 'price' with the type of 'text'.

```
{
  "desks": {
    "Dedicated Desk": "$400 mo"
  },
  "private offices": {
    "1 Person": "$550 mo",
    "2 Person": "$1100 mo",
    "3 Person": "$1600 mo",
    "4 Person": "$2100 mo",
    "6 Person": "$3300 mo"
  },
  "flexible membership": {
    "Starting at": "$45 mo",
    "Every Extra Day": "$50 Day"
  }
}
```

I then make a call from PHP to return my all the fields in my database and encode them as json.

```
$json = json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

$response is the response from the database. When I var_dump on $response I get

```
array(22) {
    [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#6 (38) {
        [...]

        ["price"]=>
        string(242) "{"desks":{"Dedicated Desk":"$400 mo"},"private offices":{"1 Person":"$550 mo","2 Person":"$1100 mo","3 Person":"$1600 mo","4 Person":"$2100 mo","6 Person":"$3300 mo"},"flexible membership":{"Starting at":"$45 mo","Every Extra Day":"$50 Day"}}"

        [...]
      }
    [...]
}
```

When I echo the result from json_encode i get

```
[
    {
        [...]

        "price": "{\"desks\":{\"Dedicated Desk\":\"$400 mo\"},\"private offices\":{\"1 Person\":\"$550 mo\",\"2 Person\":\"$1100 mo\",\"3 Person\":\"$1600 mo\",\"4 Person\":\"$2100 mo\",\"6 Person\":\"$3300 mo\"},\"flexible membership\":{\"Starting at\":\"$45 mo\",\"Every Extra Day\":\"$50 Day\"}}",

        [...]
    },
    [...]
]
```

My problem is json_encode is taking the json from the database and formatting it as a string. I am trying to get it to format it as part of a multidimensional json structure. This is what im trying to achieve:

```
[  
   {  
      "price":[  
         {  
            "desks":{  
               "Dedicated Desk":"$400 mo"
            },
            "private offices":{  
               "1 Person":"$550 mo",
               "2 Person":"$1100 mo",
               "3 Person":"$1600 mo",
               "4 Person":"$2100 mo",
               "6 Person":"$3300 mo"
            },
            "flexible membership":{  
               "Starting at":"$45 mo",
               "Every Extra Day":"$50 Day"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Running latest version of php.

Comment: you want to change first one to last one?am i right?

Answer (score 0):

It is encoding it as a string because it IS a string.  What you need to do is decode it first.

```
 $response['price'] = json_decode($response['price']);
 $json = json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 echo $json;
```

Comment: Im not exactly in a position to decode that portion and then re-encode it. Is there anything I can do from the database as to how its saved in the DB?

Comment: I'm not aware of any object storage capabilities of MySQL, which would be the only thing you could do at the database level.  Could you expound a little on not being able to decode it? If you are writing the `json_encode` line, is there no way to write just one more line?